# Laptop graphic card not working when battery is taken out but connected to power supply

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, power-supply, battery, power

I am trying to keep my battery life as much as possible so I tried taking out my laptop battery when i am gaming on it at home. However, when the battery is out of the laptop and plugged in to the power supply, my fps drops like as if i am playing on battery unplugged to power supply. How do I get it to work as if the battery is on the laptop and power supply plugged in?

I am using NVIDIA GTX 950M.

Comment: What laptop do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Solution: Don't remove the battery.

Typically, you don't need to remove modern batteries, and they are fine with being charged and kept charged - batteries will do better being kept topped up than deep cycling them.

For example: charging your phone overnight, every night, to 100% is better than "*running it down*" and only charging it when it's low.

Rapid charging and over-discharging will play into degrading the life of your battery.

Some laptops provide the ability to only charge to 50% or 70%. This will do more to prolong your battery's life than removing it and putting it on a shelf at 100% charge.

Comment: Well that is what i did. My laptop is about 2 years old. Now the battery is totally dead as i thought it would be fine leaving it in there plugged in..

Comment: This information is not clear from your question... please update it. Also please indicate what chemistry your battery is.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a definite answer as the implementation varies from laptop to laptop but some laptops come with a power adapter that is too weak to support peak energy demands. Let's say your laptop can consume 100W maximum but only does so in short peaks. The manufacturer might decide to ship your laptop with a 80W power supply and rely on the battery to act as a buffer for peak energy usage.

Dell definitely does this when you use an underpowered power supply from another Dell laptop. It'll allow you to start the laptop but the battery has to be there to act as a buffer for peak demand.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to force the power-management settings to the "maximum performance" setting.
I have seen a number of laptops (Acer and MSI models) that decided that 1 power-source equaled "battery only" en 2 power-sources meant "plugged in". Seems the software just counted the number of active power-sources and didn't actually check if one was the mains power.
So you had to override the automatic decision manually to make it use maximum performance.

Why are you taken the battery out anyway ?
For modern Li-ion based batteries there is almost no wear due to actual use. They mainly loose maximum capacity due to degradation over time regardless of whether they are used or not. (And frequently doing a full discharge isn't good either.) But actually using them doesn't make much difference.
For older NiCad batteries the usage and continuous recharging, while connected to mains could degrade them a bit faster. So taking them out when the laptop was to be used on mains power was sensible, but these batteries are only found in very old laptops. I don't think I have actually seen one after 2005 or so.

Comment: I have tried to force it to use maximum performance but it doesnt seems to work. As for why i have taken it out is because like you mentioned, i thought it wont degrade to the point where its totally dead now. Cant even hold charge at all now.

Comment: Please provide the steps to force the settings

Comment: @thhVictor Without knowing which version of Windows (or another OS) you are using I can only say you need to use the advanced options under "Power Management". Please note that some laptops just have badly designed power-management software. If yours is one of those it is possible you just can't change it. By the way: If your battery is already 100% dead, as you seem to imply in the other comment. it is better to take it out altogether as the laptop trying to re-charge the dead battery will draw a lot of power (waste of energy) and really overheat things.